# Issues with pool panel power

Tags: electrical, wiring

[image]I went outside Sunday morning and the pool pump was not running but power was working to pool light transformer and two outlets. Called an electrician, he got the pump running but after he left I noticed the transformer and outlets were not working. The transformer and one of the outlets were connected to a single pole 15 amp breaker. The other outlet was connected to a 20 amp breaker. After the fix that 20 amp breaker would trip if the power to the 15 amp was on.

I put the transformer on it's own breaker and the pool lights are now working. I also put the gfi outlet that was attached to the 15 amp breaker on its own breaker and I got intermittent/low voltage to the outlet. Not enough power to power a battery charge for my lawn tools. I then decided to replace the gfi with a 15 amp gfi and still nothing. I relized after installing that the old gfi was a 20 amp so replaced it and the breaker with 20 amp products. Still low voltage to the outlet.

Now, to my question. When I turn the transformer breaker off I get zero power to the gfi. However, when they are both on I get some power as mentioned above. Is it possible the hot line going from the panel to the outlet went bad and it is drawing power from the low voltage transformer hot? Again, I get zero power to the outlet if the transformer breaker is off.

Regarding the electrician, he wasn;t great and I don;t think he even knows how he got the pool pump running but here is what happened: he went into the basement of the house and turned the breaker off. There was a junction box that he said was wired incorrectly. He "fixed" the wiring, turned on the breaker and when we got outside the pump was running. Looking back at what happened it almost seems like he simply flipped what was working and what wasnt. He also changed the wire configuration in the panel to reflect the changes he made in the basement. Side note, I previously had issues with power to the pool panel and had a new line run about 4-5 years ago.

Any thoguhts on the breaker that is tripping are welcome too! :)

This is the panel:

Homeline 100 Amp 6-Space 12-Circuit Outdoor Main Lug Load Center

[image]

Comment: Pictures of any panels involved, including where the electrician was messing around, would be helpful. I would be very concerned because any issue that might impact proper safety (e.g., GFCI, grounding) of the pump is a **serious** issue.

Comment: It's good that you are asking for help, it sounds like these circuits have not had good luck finding competent people.   The cross-circuit breaker trip is due to a wiring blunder. What kinds depends on if the breakers have "Test" buttons.

Comment: How to add a photo? The pump and the breaker that is is tripping have "Test" buttons. The GFCI is right next to the panel and I only use to run an extension cord to my shed. The entire panel is a food 30-40 feet from pool.

Comment: @Chris -- hit [edit] in the "share edit..." links at the bottom-left of your question to get back to where you can add pictures.  Also, your panel is a QO, *not* a Homeline...can you provide more photos of the wiring in it, and information about which wires go where?

Comment: Thanks threephase! The breaker on the left is for the GFCI outlet in the photo and the transformer. The breaker in the middle controls the pool pump via a intermatic timer. The breaker on the right is for the outlet and a keyed powered pool cover that is on a single pole. There is also a pool heater connected somehow and also controlled but the intermatic timer.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, I'll call an electrician.